# How to strip filenames after first character / underscore and rename

Tags: bash, shell, replace, substring

I have a directory with filenames with this format:

**DAM3D002_P_DAPedit.jpg**

I need to rename all filenames to:

**DAM3D002.jpg**

I'm working on Linux/Ubuntu 18.04

This is what I have tried on bash:

```
for f in *.jpg; do mv "$f" "${f%_*.jpg}.jpg" ; done
```

I expect the output:

**DAM3D002.jpg**

But I'm getting:

**DAM3D002_P.jpg**

Comment: You need `"${f%%_*.jpg}.jpg"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
for f in *.jpg; do mv "$f" "${f%%_*.jpg}.jpg"; done
```

See [10.1. Manipulating Strings](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

> `${string%%substring}`
>   Deletes longest match of *$substring* from *back* of *$string*.

As is [noted by  l'L'l](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56120540/how-to-strip-filenames-after-first-character-underscore-and-rename/56120654?noredirect=1#comment98875784_56120654), in case your *.jpg file names may contain no underscores, the above solution will add a second `.jpg` to the end of the file name. If that is undesired, use

```
for f in *.jpg; do echo "${f/_*.jpg/.jpg}"; done
```

[Online test](https://ideone.com/8tii8E):

```
files=(1.jpg 1_2.jpg 1_2_3.jpg /a/b/c/1_2_3.jpg)
for f in "${files[@]}"; do echo "${f/_*.jpg/.jpg}"; done
```

Output:

```
1.jpg
1.jpg
1.jpg
/a/b/c/1.jpg
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if there are any `jpg` files without an underscore it will change the name to `file.jpg.jpg`. It would probably be better to use `${f/_*.jpg/.jpg}`.